# How to launch Google Colab with local runtime which is an existing Docker image?

Tags: docker, jupyter-notebook

I would like to connect Google Colab with a local runtime which is an existing Docker image. Specifically, FEniCS allows launching a notebook, i. e

```
docker run --name notebook -w /home/fenics -v $(pwd):/home/fenics/shared -d -p 127.0.0.1:8888:8888 quay.io/fenicsproject/stable 'jupyter-notebook --ip=0.0.0.0'
```

How can I launch it with Google Colab also with Backend port 8888?

I tried to build the image from a crash following the work [here](https://github.com/prakashdbhagat/docker-google-colab) for Ubuntu 18.04. I could connect the local runtime with this image but it crashed whenever I installed FEniCS. There is something missing it seems. I really appreciate any hints.